# Building native image using quarkus on a M1 Mac fails

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, apple-m1, graalvm-native-image

From my project's root directory, I issued the following command to create a native executable that will be specific to my operating system. [See the following guide for details](https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#build-a-container-friendly-executable)

```
mvn package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

and here is the output.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.example:quarkus-spring >---------------------
[INFO] Building quarkus-spring 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:generate-code (default) @ quarkus-spring ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ quarkus-spring ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ quarkus-spring ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:generate-code-tests (default) @ quarkus-spring ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ quarkus-spring ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ quarkus-spring ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ quarkus-spring ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.controller.GreetingControllerTest
2021-06-22 21:17:05,339 WARN  [io.qua.dat.dep.dev.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor] (build-10) Unable to determine a database type for default datasource
2021-06-22 21:17:05,340 WARN  [io.qua.agr.dep.AgroalProcessor] (build-16) The Agroal dependency is present but no JDBC datasources have been defined.
2021-06-22 21:17:06,080 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.13.7.Final on JVM started in 1.004s. Listening on: http://localhost:8081
2021-06-22 21:17:06,081 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated.
2021-06-22 21:17:06,081 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, hibernate-orm-panache, mongodb-client, mutiny, narayana-jta, resteasy, smallrye-context-propagation, spring-boot-properties, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-di]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.755 s - in com.example.controller.GreetingControllerTest
2021-06-22 21:17:06,699 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus stopped in 0.020s
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ quarkus-spring ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:build (default) @ quarkus-spring ---
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.2.0.Final
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor] The Agroal dependency is present but no JDBC datasources have been defined.
[INFO] [org.hibernate.Version] HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building native image source jar: /Users/viswanath/projects/quarkus-spring/target/quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Building native image from /Users/viswanath/projects/quarkus-spring/target/quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildContainerRunner] Using docker to run the native image builder
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildContainerRunner] Checking image status quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.0-java11
21.0-java11: Pulling from quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image
Digest: sha256:356624049da5f564e14acbaf167a341a01b332569db83e9967b1e72cfdf06653
Status: Image is up to date for quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.0-java11
quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.0-java11
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Running Quarkus native-image plugin on GraalVM Version 21.0.0.2 (Java Version 11.0.10+8-jvmci-21.0-b06)
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildRunner] docker run --env LANG=C --rm -v /Users/viswanath/projects/quarkus-spring/target/quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar:/project:z quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.0-java11 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-DCoordinatorEnvironmentBean.transactionStatusManagerEnable=false -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=1 -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=GB -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy\$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -H:+AllowFoldMethods -jar quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -J-Xmx8192m -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https --enable-all-security-services --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
^C%
```

**Native image generation fails as the build just hangs.**

---

I chose to install Graal VM on my host and opt for the non-container based approach as shown below.

- Install Graal VM on M1 Mac using the following command

  ❯ brew install --cask graalvm/tap/graalvm-ce-lts-java11
- Add Graal VM to JEnv managed versions of Java

  ❯ jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-lts-java11-20.3.1/Contents/Home
  graalvm64-11.0.10 added
- For the project, set Graal VM's Java 11. From the project's directory, issue the following command

  ❯ jenv local graalvm64-11.0.10
- Set GRAALVM_HOME environment variable to the GraalVM installation directory. Add the following to ~/.zshrc

  ❯ export GRAALVM_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-lts-java11-20.3.1/Contents/Home

and reload changes made to .zshrc by issuing the command

```
❯ source ~/.zshrc
```

- Install the native-image tool using the following command. Some previous releases of GraalVM included the native-image tool by default. This is no longer the case; it must be installed as a second step after GraalVM itself is installed.

  ❯ ${GRAALVM_HOME}/bin/gu install native-image
- Install binutils and add it to the path

  ❯ brew install binutils

  ❯ echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/binutils/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  ❯ source ~/.zshrc
- Create a native executable using the following caommand from project's root directory

  ❯ mvn clean install -Pnative -Dnative-image.docker-build=true -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=4g

Finally when I ran the native image, it failed.

```
❯ ~/projects/quarkus-spring/target ./quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner                                      
[1]    11638 killed     ./quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
```

Any help?

Comment: [This bug](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2666) seems to indicate that M1 support is not complete yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image) explains that `-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true` option means that you want to build a **Linux** executable and that the build should happen in a container.
You can even control the runtime for that Docker/Podman with:

```
# Docker
./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=docker
# Podman
./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=podman
```

It's likely the reason why the executable doesn't work on MacOS after your last command since it's a Linux binary. You can check that with:

```
file ./quarkus-spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
```

Though in the command line you're using "-Dquarkus.native.docker-build=true" instead of "-Dquarkus.native.container-build.true", and I don't know if has any relevance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it seems that the native linux image built is for x86-64 architecture. Can one also build an image for arm 64 architecture?

Comment: GraalVM works on Linux aarch64, you (here's for example the link to the current base binary: https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-21.1.0/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-aarch64-21.1.0.tar.gz) 

You'll need corresponding hardware though to run it. Here's an example of using Oracle cloud free Arm VM for building native image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fh009OWr8Ks

Answer (score 0):

This [Answer from another similar question worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71368601/8870794).  Basically you just need to build base graalvm image on your M1 laptop and reference that image (e.g. here the image is tagged as `graalvm`) using `-Dquarkus.native.builder-image=graalvm`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macOS Catalina and later you may need to remove the quarantine attribute from the bits before you can use them
To do this, run the following:

```
$ sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine path/to/graalvm/folder/
```

Based on Graal commit: https://github.com/oracle/graal/tree/vm-22.1.0