# Building quarkus native Linux/amd64 (x86_64) image & container from Apple M1 (Arm) using Maven

Tags: docker, maven, quarkus-native

This is a follow up question on [Building quarkus native Linux/amd64 (x86_64) image from Apple M1 (Arm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960783/building-quarkus-native-linux-amd64-x86-64-image-from-apple-m1-arm) with which I am still struggling.

I have the exact same issue (although using maven). I am trying to build a linux/amd64 native image on an Apple M1 using Maven. Has anyone been able to do this?

I've tried various different configurations, but the resulting runner/docker image always seems to be build for the arm64 (aarch64) architecture or gets stuck (see [16225](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/16225))

Here's (one of) my maven build commands, based on https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image

```
mvn clean package -Pnative -e \
-Dmaven.test.skip=true \
-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true \
-Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:22.3-java17 \
-Dquarkus.container-image.build=true \
-Dquarkus.container-image.push=true
```

Replacing `-Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:22.3-java17` with `-Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:22.3.1.0-Final-java17-amd64` causes the build to get stuck.

and here the content of my Dockerfile.native (not sure if it's relevant):

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.7
WORKDIR /work/
COPY target/*-runner /work/application
RUN chmod 775 /work
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

The output of the -runner quarkus executable remains to be

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0
```

and when running `uname -m` on the terminal (Docker) it states `aarch64`.

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't been able to find an answer to that, have you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've ended up using github actions to build the container image.

Answer (score 0):

**Two steps**:

1. Build executable: `./mvnw clean package -Dnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-graalvmce-builder-image:jdk-21.0.2-amd64 -DskipTests`
2. Build image: `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native -t your-image-amd64 .`

Important to use **amd64 image** for `-Dquarkus.native.builder-image` and **linux/amd64** for `--platform`.

*Note: build is slow.*