# Quarkus native application on AWS EKS - "exec format error"

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy a Quarkus-Camel native app to AWS EKS but getting the log error:
`exec ./application: exec format error`

The app works fine in my local minikube environment and I've ensure that the os/arch of the image is `linux/arm64`. I have another app which I am building & deploying the exact same way which works without any issues.

The pod state (`kubectl describe pod`) is:

```
Name:             integration-order-6dbccccb7d-qm9sb
Namespace:        development
Priority:         0
Service Account:  integration-order
Node:             ip-192-168-31-231.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/192.168.31.231
Start Time:       Sun, 12 Mar 2023 21:49:05 +1100
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/name=integration-order
                  app.kubernetes.io/version=1.0.0
                  pod-template-hash=6dbccccb7d
Annotations:      app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2023-03-12 - 09:59:34 +0000
                  app.quarkus.io/commit-id: b888f2e29a05851b20d400386d70f3b269c3ed7a
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.6.84
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.6.84
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/integration-order-6dbccccb7d
Containers:
  integration-order:
    Container ID:   containerd://6cd1d5c2459d00ea17e28528a06e73846cdad78cb2f4d03696427f88f2107bd2
    Image:          fluentintegrations/integration-order:1.0.0
    Image ID:       docker.io/fluentintegrations/integration-order@sha256:eb42f2faf67cd61b0eb8e805aa6a46d5649db1b4aafd448319cf50bec6f476f2
    Port:           8087/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sun, 12 Mar 2023 21:49:22 +1100
      Finished:     Sun, 12 Mar 2023 21:49:22 +1100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sun, 12 Mar 2023 21:49:06 +1100
      Finished:     Sun, 12 Mar 2023 21:49:06 +1100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  2
    Liveness:       http-get http://:8087/q/health/live delay=30s timeout=10s period=30s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:8087/q/health/ready delay=45s timeout=10s period=45s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE:  development (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-rmczh (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-rmczh:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  20s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned development/integration-order-6dbccccb7d-qm9sb to ip-192-168-31-231.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulled     3s (x3 over 20s)  kubelet            Container image "fluentintegrations/integration-order:1.0.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    3s (x3 over 20s)  kubelet            Created container integration-order
  Normal   Started    3s (x3 over 20s)  kubelet            Started container integration-order
  Warning  BackOff    2s (x3 over 18s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Maven command:

```
 mvn clean package -Pnative -e \
-Dmaven.test.skip=true \
-Dquarkus.native.remote-container-build=true \
-Dquarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true \
-Dquarkus.container-image.push=true
```

application.properties:

```
quarkus.http.port=8087

# quarkus kubernetes extension
quarkus.container-image.group=fluentintegrations
quarkus.container-image.name=integration-order
quarkus.kubernetes.namespace=development
quarkus.kubernetes.readiness-probe.initial-delay=45s
quarkus.kubernetes.readiness-probe.period=45s
quarkus.kubernetes.liveness-probe.initial-delay=30s
quarkus.kubernetes.liveness-probe.period=30s
quarkus.kubernetes.image-pull-policy=ifNotPresent
quarkus.kubernetes.service-type=LoadBalancer
```

I am running this on a Mac M1. Any help or suggestions on what could go wrong / how to investigate further would be much appreciated.

I've checked & compared most of the configurations but am unable to identify why one works the other doesn't. I have tried all the suggested steps here:https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-pod-status-troubleshooting/

Comment: `file ./target/<hidden>-1.0.2-runner` returns:
./target/<hidden>1.0.2-runner: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=c98cca38c173d1957522d36a713c6210c4325976, not stripped


Am I building the runner incorrectly?

Comment: You're trying to run this Pod on an Arm/Graviton instance? Can you add the Pod's logs to this question?

Comment: usually its becauase different architecture, your pod need to support multi-arch or have dedicated tags for arm64 / amd64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Jeremy Cowan & @gumelaragum!

Creating the cluster with the parameter `--node-type=m6g.large` resolved my issue and I'm able to run the images on EKS.

Question:
Is there a way to build the artifacts for a x86_64 architecture on a Mac M1? I  found a few threads stating that `-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true` or using a separate builder image ([Issue compiling quarkus native image on Apple Sillicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337504/issue-compiling-quarkus-native-image-on-apple-sillicon/71368601#71368601))resolved the issue, but none of them worked for me and the file type would always state `ARM aarch64`.

Would Maven play a role here?

Comment: If you want to raise a new question, you should do so. Don't ask questions in answers.